# Array Field vs Character Varying Performance in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where a column is of type character varying. There, we store an stringified array which we then convert inside our application code.

Now We are experiencing performance issues when doing update operations on this column. It takes 2-3 mins to update the field. The array size is usually 3000-10000 items.

I was thinking that changing the field to an array field could help with the performance time but I wanted to confirm this. And also if youbhave any other ideas to reduce the update time on this table. We would ideally like for it to be in the order of s or ms.

Thanks

I'm adding the output of an explain analyze of this query:

```
UPDATE events_table array_list_events=%(keyframe_list)s WHERE id = %(events_table_id)s

"Update on events_table  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=656) (actual time=1.951..1.951 rows=0 loops=1)"

"  ->  Index Scan using events_table on sequence  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=656) (actual time=1.433..1.434 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (id = 911813)"

"Planning Time: 0.706 ms"

"Execution Time: 2.006 ms"
```

What I cannot understand is that doing it manually multiple times returns pretty fast. But we have records of this query taking 100 seconds too, what could be causing this?

Comment: Do you know if the 2-3 min is spent in DB or in your application code? I'd expect postgres to perform better even with large column sizes.

Comment: Accordong to our monitoring systems the time it takes is specifically in the update. The application ends out giving a timeout but its because of the update queyr.Im not sure if maybe a vaccum or something similar might be needed?  We've never done one

Comment: if you aren't using something like pghero (https://github.com/ankane/pghero) i'd strongly recommend. Running a vacuum/analyze is never a bad idea. Your large values (over 2kb) would be stored in TOAST and so wouldn't greatly impact normal table size/performance

Comment: Generally I'd question the wisdom of storing 3k-10k length arrays as text fields in a database (versus breaking them out into a separate table with 3k-10k associated rows that you join in), but it's hard to say without understanding the use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even writing a long `text` or `varchar` like this will never take that long in PostgreSQL. Please provide `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for the statement to verify that.

One possible explanation for a short operation like that to take such a long time could be a concurrent long running transaction that holds a conflicting lock that blocks the update. Set `log_lock_waits = on` and see if you get any messages in the PostgreSQL log.

No matter if you store an array in a string or in a proper array data type, it will always be one large thing, and the `UPDATE` should take about the same time.

If you never use the array elements inside the database, and all you do is store and retrieve the thing, using a `text` or `varchar` column might be preferable from a performance point of view. If you access array elements inside the database, or you want PostgreSQL to check if the syntax of the array is correct, use an array type.

Comment: Perhaps it is a lock; see my updated answer.